# the stack's role with format strings

Tags: c, parameters, stack, printf, format-string

Okay this is going to be somewhat lengthy.

So I've got a program that uses two `%n` format parameters in it's a `printf()` statement. `%n` essentially writes data without displaying anything... So when my format function encounters `%n` parameter, it writes the number of bites that have been written by the function to the address of the corresponding function argument.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main() {

 int A = 5, B = 7, count_one, count_two;

 printf("The number of bytes written up to this point X%n is being stored in
 count_one, and the number of bytes up to here X%n is being stored in
 count_two.\n", &count_one, &count_two);

 printf("count_one: %d\n", count_one);
 printf("count_two: %d\n", count_two);

 printf("A is %d and is at %08x. B is %x.\n", A, &A, B);

 exit(0); 
 }
```

the output of the program is:

```
The number of bytes written up to this point X is being stored in count_one,and the number of bytes up to here X is being stored in count_two.
count_one: 46
count_two: 113
A is 5 and is at bffff7f4. B is 7.
```

---

With regards to this printf

> printf("A is %d and is at %08x. B is %x.\n", A, &A, B);

Now, the arguments are pushes to the stack in reverse order first the value of B then the value address of A then the value address of A, and finally the address of the format string...

Now if only two arguments are pushed to the stack with a format string that uses three format parameters?

So I removed the last argument in the code above to match this printf() argument

> printf("A is %d and is at %08x. B is %x.\n", A, &A);

and what happens when I compile and execute is...

```
The number of bytes written up to this point X is being stored in count_one, and the number of
bytes up to here X is being stored in count_two.
count_one: 46
count_two: 113
A is 5 and is at bffffc24. B is b7fd6ff4
```

So I get this `b7fd6ff4`, what is that? What does this mean with relations to the stack frame for the format function?

Any insight or explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: The only *general* explanation has two words here *undefined behavior*. Stacks and stuff are implementation specific and irrelevant.

Comment: the posted code, as posted, does not compile!  the first call to `printf()` has a format string (first parameter) that is invalid.  Now, if that 3 line string were all on one line ...

Comment: the second format specifier of the last call to `printf()` should be '%p` not '%08x"

Comment: the posted code is missing one or more statements (most likely a '}') at the end of the code

Comment: Rather than post an approximation of true code, it is more clear to post true compilable code.

Comment: @chux it is "true code" save it as a .c then gcc whatever.c then ./a.out and it'll run

Comment: @user3629249 no it should be %08x why would it be %p???

Comment: Posted code does not compile.  Try cut/paste from the post to see.

Comment: `"%08x"` is for printing `unsigned`, not pointers.  `"%p"` is for printing `void*` pointers.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having either the wrong number of format specifiers or mismatched format specifiers invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From section 7.21.6.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `fprintf` function:

> *9* If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.282) If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

What this means is that you can't make any reliable prediction about what value the function will receive if you don't pass it enough parameters.  What will most likely happen in an implementation that uses a stack and has optimizations disabled is that it will grab whatever value happens to be next in memory next to the last parameter pushed onto the stack.

Comment: ohhh so what your saying is that since the 3rd value want pushed to the stack the format function pulls the data from where the third argument should have been? if so is that done by adding to the current frame pointer?? if not how?

Comment: @Boschko Yes, that's done by adding to the current frame pointer. Assuming you're working with x86 then all arguments are passed on the stack and the callee function retrieves those arguments by walking up the stack. Usually the compiler generates an error when a function isn't called with the right number of arguments, but printf() is a *variadic function* and is allowed to be called with any number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. fixes the problems listed in the comments to the question
2. cleanly compiles
3. performs the desired functionality

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int A = 5;
    int B = 7;
    int count_one;
    int count_two;

    printf("The number of bytes written up to this point X%n is being stored"
        " in count_one, and the number of bytes up to here X%n is being"
        " stored in count_two.\n",
        &count_one,
        &count_two);

    printf("count_one: %d\n", count_one);
    printf("count_two: %d\n", count_two);

    printf("A is %d and is at %p. B is %x.\n", A, (void*)&A, B);

    exit(0);
}
```

a typical run of the program results in:

```
The number of bytes written up to this point X is being stored in count_one, and the number of bytes up to here X is being stored in count_two.
count_one: 46
count_two: 113
A is 5 and is at 0x7fff19c28ea8. B is 7.
```

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: Try removing the last argument from the printf so it matches `printf("A is %d and is at %08x. B is %x.\n", A, &A);` and you wont get B is 7

Comment: and it doesnt make sence if youve got 3 format parameters and only 2 arguments are pushed how can 7 be the first value found below the stack frame for the format function

Comment: @Boschko,   the number of format specifiers must match the number of following parameters in a call to `printf()`.   Otherwise the result is undefined behavior.  You 'never' want your code to contain undefined behavior  Exactly what will happen when you break that rule depends on the surrounding data on the stack and the specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Under the 32-bit x86 calling convention all function parameters are passed on the stack. If you call `printf()` with more format specifiers than arguments the function will gladly keep walking up the stack and grabbing whatever values are there to find something to display.

The specific contents of the stack are going to be variable- usually function-local variables, function return pointers, or stack pointers.

Comment: so basically the 3rd value wasnt pushed to the stack? right, so then where did the format function pull data from?

Comment: Is not the calling convention used determine by the compiler and not the platform?  Of course a platform has limitations, but there must be many calling conventions a compiler may select.

Comment: @Boschko Right. When you call printf with three format specifiers and two arguments (after the string) then it will find the third value on the stack where it normally expects it to be. The size of the arguments is determined by the size of the data given in the format specifier. E.g. an int corresponds to a 4-byte value, a double corresponds to an 8-byte value, etc.

Comment: @chux You're right, the calling convention is determined by the language/compiler. But in the context of a question about C/C++, the x86 calling convention can only mean "the C-style x86 calling convention"

Answer (score 0):

printf assumes that you pushed all 4 arguments on the stack.  It is expecting B to be on the stack regardless of whether you provided it or not.  If you did not provide it then it will use whatever is in that memory location and print it.

Comment: "printf assumes that you pushed all 4 arguments on the stack" is certainly an implementation detail.  It is not specified by C.

Comment: well it'd be something like {top of stack} Address format string, Value of A, Value of A, Value of B {bottom of stack} as a general rule the format function iterates through the format string one character at a time... so if its not at the beginning of a format parameter, the character is copied to the output. right?